# Can I implements http/2 server without ALPN support?

Tags: http2, alpn

In this way, the client can connect the server without ALPN and use http/2 default.

Is that possible？

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is possible, but the conditions are strict.

Browsers, as of now, do not implement clear-text communication for HTTP/2, so if you use a browser the answer to your question is no: you have to deploy your server with ALPN support if you want browsers to be able to connect.

On the other hand, other clients such as Java clients may be able to connect to a server using clear-text HTTP/2, so for those type of clients the answer to your question is yes: you can deploy a HTTP/2 server without ALPN support.

The [Jetty Project](http://eclipse.org/jetty) [disclaimer, I am a committer] implements a web server and servlet container that support both scenarios: you can enable ALPN for TLS (SSL) HTTP/2 communication so that browsers will be able to connect, and you can also enable clear-text HTTP/2 communication as [explained here](https://webtide.com/jetty-http2-cleartext-upgrade/). See also the [Jetty HTTP/2 documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http2.html).

Comment: Not exactly what was asked, but lots of servers also accept NPN instead of ALPN... =)

Comment: @sbordet，any possible to run server whit http/2 over TLS connection directly?so the client  can connect to the server without ALPN and use http/2 default?

Comment: This is possible only if the client knows beforehand that the server accepts HTTP/2 over TLS on the port you are connecting to. Servers may send the "Alt-Svc" header to tell clients what port/protocol they support, and clients that implement Alt-Svc would be able to connect using HTTP/2 over TLS without ALPN.

Comment: @sbordet So if my server will send the Alt-Svc header, will Chrome clients be able to use HTTP/2 over TLS without ALPN? Also will other browsers do as well?