# Upgrade:h2c header not present in Google Chrome requests

Tags: google-chrome, http2

I was reading the HTTP2 spec, and it explains [how a server discovers if the client supports HTTP2](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#discover-http), the client must sent a HTTP header `Upgrade:h2` however when I look to what Google Chrome is sending, it is sending the usual headers, no mention of `h2`.

It is obvious that Chrome supports HTTP2 because when accessing https://http2.akamai.com/demo/h2_demo_frame.html I can see the protocol H2 being used. I guess that is connecting through the ALPN method, but why is not sending the `Upgrade:h2` header when accessing an HTTP2:// that does not support ALPN?

I have tried with both http and https.

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe you want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132059/can-i-implements-http-2-server-without-alpn-support

Comment: Grand thanks, that answered the question.